# Emacs + AUCtex on Windows 8.1

Tags: emacs, windows, auctex

I tried to install Emacs and AUCtex on Windows 8.1 without success (at least, it does not seem to work to me). With the risk of being pedantic, here are the steps I followed:

1) Extracted the most updates emacs zip folder in c:/Program Files(x86)/Emacs/emacs-24.4

(emacs per se seems to work. If I open a .tex file, in the menu appears "TeX", I can compile with pdftex using C-c C-c , etc.)

2) Extracted the AUCtex zip folder in the same location.

Now, if I open a .tex file with emacs, nothing has changed with respect to the previous situation.

Do I miss some steps?

Comment: If you have Emacs 24.4, the easiest way to install AUCTeX is ELPA: issue `M-x package-install RET auctex RET` and you're done.  You may need to restart Emacs to make the change effective.

Comment: Thank you! Just another thing: At the end of the installation, you read "Total of 176 files compiled, 1 skipped in 4 directories". Is that skipped file an issue?

Comment: No, it's normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GNU Emacs 24 or later, you should definitely read the [AUCTeX manual](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Installation)

> **1.2 Installing AUCTeX**
>
> The simplest way of installing AUCTeX is by using the Emacs package manager integrated in Emacs 24 and greater (ELPA). Simply do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-list-packages` <kbd>RET</kbd>, mark the `auctex` package for installation with <kbd>i</kbd>, and hit <kbd>x</kbd> to execute the installation procedure. That’s all.

Or, more simply, issue <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `auctex` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally used a distribution of emacs which has both AUCTeX and Aspell and is available at
http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/.